# ImportError: sys.meta_path is None, Python is likely shutting down in Python OpenAI CartPole

Tags: python, python-3.x, openai-gym

I was just getting started to learn OpenAI. I write my first OpenAI code, i want to make CartPole AI. But something happened. Here is my code

```
import gym

# Environment
env = gym.make('CartPole-v0')

# Obsevation
obs = env.reset()

for _ in range(100):
    env.render()

    cart_pos,cart_vel,ang,ang_vel = obs

    if ang > 0:
        action = 1
    else:
        action = 0

    obs,reward,done,info = env.step(action)
```

When i run the code, a warning is printed

```
(base) F:\Python Scripts\CartPole-OpenAI>python CartPole.py
C:\Users\PHILIP\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\gym\logger.py:30: UserWarning: [33mWARN: You are calling 'step()' even though this environment has already returned done = True. You should always call 'reset()' once you receive 'done = True' -- any further steps are undefined behavior.[0m
  warnings.warn(colorize('%s: %s'%('WARN', msg % args), 'yellow'))
```

When the loop is done

```
Exception ignored in: <function Viewer.__del__ at 0x00000209A1788048>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\PHILIP\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\gym\envs\classic_control\rendering.py", line 162, in __del__
  File "C:\Users\PHILIP\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\gym\envs\classic_control\rendering.py", line 81, in close
  File "C:\Users\PHILIP\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyglet\window\win32\__init__.py", line 299, in close
  File "C:\Users\PHILIP\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyglet\window\__init__.py", line 820, in close
ImportError: sys.meta_path is None, Python is likely shutting down
```

I appreciate your help. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding

```sh
env.close()
```

or

```sh
env.env.close()
```

to the extreme end of the sript